# nested class form of composite notation in staruml

Tags: uml, staruml

How to draw nested class form of composite notation in starUML? I use the part and connector to draw a class diagram like this. I suppressed the attributes because the parts ( the nested classes) also appear as attributes. But I can not use part and connector in object diagram. So I drew two objects within one object to appear like this. But I don’t think it is the right way.  Can someone pleases help me?

[image]

Comment: What you show is not nesting, but composition.

Comment: it is just called composition? But it shows the parts inside the class. I don't know how to draw it in StarUML.

Comment: Ah, sorry. You mean the two header classes?

Comment: I do not know about two header classes. Mailmessage consists  of one header and one body. I want to draw that  as the above diagram.

Comment: I don't understand your question. You say you "suppressed the attributes because the parts (the nested classes) also appear as attributes," but showing attributes as parts is the *entire point* of a composite structure diagram. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @JimL. I guess he wants to see `Header` and `Body` as attribute in the `:MailMessage' object. Not as separate objects.

Answer (score 0):

For nested classes, you could make the connections with [containment](https://docs.staruml.io/working-with-uml-diagrams/package-diagram#containment) from "package-diagram"